# Is it possible to insert rcords in lobos migration plugin for clojure?

Tags: mysql, database, clojure, migration

In clojure, I am using lobos library with "mysql/mysql-connector-java" dependency.
I've created some master tables using lobos migration library in clojure. 
Now I need to insert some of the default values through the migration itself. 
Is there any way the library provide or should I use any other library to write DB migration.
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your DDL you can specify the a default value for the column.

See documentation https://github.com/budu/lobos/blob/master/src/lobos/schema.clj#L382

```
(defrecord Column [cname data-type default auto-inc not-null others] ...
```